# How to properly trigger path mtu discovery

Tags: macos, network, tcp

I've activate the pmtu attribute in my machine.

```
sysctl net.inet.tcp.path_mtu_discovery
net.inet.tcp.path_mtu_discovery: 1
```

then I've used `/usr/bin/nscurl` to send messages to a remote gateway with mtu=1000, in hope that it will trigger the pmtu automatically. However, I still witness packet fragmentation.

> I Used nscurl since In Apple forum https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/710848
> it looks that if I use `NSURLSession` framework, it also perform pmtu discover behind the scenes.

My question is how can I read the pmtu cache and check what is the selected mtu for a specific path (i've tried `netstat -rn` but it mtu is missing there)

Also, what is the best way to trigger pmtu discovery?

UPDATE : after analyzing nscurl traffic, it looks like the pmtu is being calculated on each message passing. However, once the connection is closed, I pmtu is removed and it's being re-calculated all over again.

the following packet dump show that first, we try mtu size packets (size 1500) with DF bit set. the rest of the message is sent with ~1000 bytes sized packets (i've deliberately set the mtu of one of the hops to 1000). The problem is that if I try nscurl again, it re-calulate the mtu all over again. I want to be able to read the calculated pmtu and use it elsewhere.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initiating a new connection and sending larger-than-MTU packets should be enough. You should also be able to force it by downing and upping the interface.

Note that path MTU discovery won't be active on IPv6 connections, and it is not active when you have locked the MTU on the route. There's a black-hole detection mechanism as well that can disable path MTU discovery.

You haven't detailed how you're checking that you are still seeing packet fragmentation. I would recommend using a tool such as Wireshark (or tcpdump) to record the network packets from the time of upping the interface over establishing the connection and transferring data for a bit.

Then look over the recorded trace in Wireshark to check for packet sizes and the MF-flag (check if the packets are actually fragmented, and not just small).

Note that the path MTU discovery packets will have the DF flag set.

Regarding how to check the "pmtu cache" (which is really not a cache as such), you can do that by running this command:

```
lsof -i -n -Tf
```

It will display the network connections and list the MSS values (maximum segment size). This is the value that could have been found through path MTU discovery.

UPDATE:

You have edited your question, where you ask why the MTU value found through path MTU discovery is not reused for other connections. That would kind of defeat the purpose of path MTU discovery - the main assumption is that different paths could have different MTUs. So different connections could possibly take different paths, and so must have their own, seperate MTU calculation.

Note that the path MTU discovery process should take declared MTUs of the involved network interface into account.

If you want to set a fixed MTU for a specific route, you can set that in the route table.

Comment: Perhaps you can show me an easy way of how to send IP packets with different size - so I can trigger the pmtu discovery. also, do you know how to read the pmtu cache ? it must be written somewhere so the network layer will know which packet size to use for a specific connection, right?

Comment: An easy way to send packets with different sizes is to use the "-s" argument for ping.

Comment: @Zohar81 I have extended the answer with how to look up which packet sizes are used for each specific connection.

Comment: Hi, Perhaps you can also refer to another question of mine about how to set the pmtu for specific path https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/463034/setting-fix-mtu-for-a-specific-destination