# Setting fix MTU for a specific destination

Tags: macos, network

Basically I want to avoid the pmtu discovery for every new connection using high level network frameworks such as NSURLSession (used by nscurl) and set the mtu in advance. I'm using macOS Ventura and I guess it can be done using `netstat`, but I couldn't find how.

How can I set the path mtu for specific route (from local to some remote IP address) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly trigger path mtu discovery](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/462989/how-to-properly-trigger-path-mtu-discovery)

Comment: @LincD. The question specifically says they want to avoid PMTU Discovery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do that by adding a static route using the `route` command - just like any other route, and add the `-mtu` argument to specify the initial MTU.